# Profiling Unity iOS App with Unity Free

Tags: unity-game-engine, profiling, instruments

Is there any recommendations for profiling your iOS app without a pro licence. Running it though Instruments does not show any of function names etc (I'm trying to locate the functions that are taking up the most time) and the default Unity profiler for free, while useful, doesn't provide such in-depth analysis that I need.

I've looked in the Asset Store and there doesn't appear to be any good profilers that support iOS. Is my only option to get Unity Pro and iOS Unity Pro?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to build your own profiler.